# changing roslaunch parameter

Tags: ros, roslaunch, parameter, uvc-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I would like to use an external webcam with a laptop that already has a built-in webcam which is mapped to /dev/video0.
The uvc_camera node wants to use /dev/video0 and  would like to change it to /dev/video1 is there any way to change the parameter from command line?
I know I could change the .launch file, but I don't want to touch it.
I tried to run roslaunch as follows, but it didn't work:

```
roslaunch uvc_camera camera_node.launch device:=/dev/video1
```

What is the best way to change a parameter in roslaunch without editing the original roslaunch file?

**Update 1:**

In the meantime I just found out, that if I copy the original launch file to somewhere in my home directory, I can edit it and I can launch it from there as well. This was probably too obvious, but I was confused by having the package name after the roslaunch command. For example:

```
cp /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/camera_umd/uvc_camera/launch/camera_node.launch /home/user/ros_workspace/
roslaunch /home/user/ros_workspace/camera_node.launch
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60062/changing-roslaunch-parameter/) by [ZoltanS](https://answers.ros.org/users/4436/zoltans/) on ROS Answers with karma: 248 on 2013-04-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you said, no parameters are defined for that launch script. It is possible to add them.

- **Simple solution**: make a copy of the script in a package of your own (e.g. **my_camera_params**), and edit to taste.
- **Complete solution**: open an enhancement ticket, fork [that UMD git repository](http://ram.umd.edu/git/ros/camera_umd.git), add `<arg>` tags for all the parameters, submit a pull request to Ken Tossell.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) on 2013-04-05**:
You can also modify the (private) parameter value after the launch file has run, from the calling/external code.  This technique will not help in this case, though, since the uvc_camera node only reads the parameter value at initial start-up.